# Angular repeaters element in collection

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to learn angular. I am having a hard time understanding part of this: http://www.learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/repeaters

In that example we're looping through a collection and displaying each element. Easy enough.

What I don't understand is: the collection is named "products" and each element is referred to as "product" no where in the JS code is the word product. How does angular know to call the element by "product"? Does a collection have to be plural and an element singular in name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identifier is assigned in the view (aka, the HTML):

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products">
```

`ng-repeat` takes an expression that defines the identifier it will assign elements in the collection. So, in this case, you bind each item in `products` to `product`. This is then accessible in the scope, so any child element of the `tr` can access `product` on the scope as `$scope.product`.

You can name the identifier anything you want. `product in products` is equally as valid as `bananas in apple`, so long as your collection is on `$scope.apple` and you use the identifier `bananas` to refer to the item in each collection.

Answer (score 0):

The first variable name passed to an `ng-repeat` is scoped to that `ng-repeat`. It's only on the template, not in the JS code, and is only available in that repeat block. So, it's essentially made up. Common conventions have people call it the singular form of the plural array (i.e. `for product in products`, `for item in items`, etc.), but that variable **only** refers to the current `ng-repeat` element on the template inside the `ng-repeat`.